Create a bullet list in Word using C#
I am trying to create a bullet list in Word over a series of paragraphs using C#. Reading up on this it looks like I have to create a 'Range' from the first paragraph to the last paragraph I want in the list and then apply a list template to the range. My current code is:
var ListRange = Document.Range(FirstParagraph.Range.Start, LastParagraph.Range.End);

var Gallery = Document.Application.ListGalleries[WdListGalleryType.wdBulletGallery];

ListRange.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate(Gallery.ListTemplates[1], WdListApplyTo.wdListApplyToWholeList);

The paragraphs I want in the range appear OK but they are not in a bullet list. Any idea what I am doing wrong.
Thanks.

If I was "desperate", I would just prepend my own "bullet icon" to the front of a paragraph. ➊➋➌➍➎➏

Nigel, try this code:
// Applies bulltets
private static void applyBullets(Word.Application ap, Word.Paragraphs paragraphs, Word.Document doc)
{
    var Gallery = ap.ListGalleries[WdListGalleryType.wdBulletGallery];
    Word.Range rng;
        
    foreach(Word.Paragraph par in paragraphs)
    {
        rng = par.Range.Duplicate;                
        rng.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate(Gallery.ListTemplates[1], WdListApplyTo.wdListApplyToWholeList);
    }
}

 // Creates paragraphs
 private static Word.Paragraphs createParagraphs(Word.Document doc)
 {            
     return doc.Paragraphs;  // Change to your needs
 }

 // Opens Word document and calls functions to set paragraphs and formatting
 public static void openWord()
 {
     Word.Application ap = new Word.Application();
     Word.Document doc = new Word.Document();
     Word.Paragraphs tmpParagraphs;

     ap.Visible = true;                      // Optional
     doc = ap.Documents.Open(@"test.docx");  // Change to your file

     // You can also declare 'ap' and 'doc' as 'globals' in your code instead of sending as parameters               
     tmpParagraphs = createParagraphs(doc);  // Create paragraphs for document 'doc'
     applyBullets(ap,tmpParagraphs,doc);     // Apply bullets to 'doc'
                                                
     doc.Save();                             // Saves changes
     doc.Close();                            // Closes document
     ap.Quit();                              // Closes Word application
}


Thanks - that helped me fix it but I found a weird error. In my application I create paragraph text in a separate method which returns a reference to the paragraph created. If I do this and then ApplyListTemplate to the response from the method it does not work. If I apply the template in the method it does.

Nigel, see my edited answer . I hope it will be useful.
